# Wrong result with linearlayout and layout weights

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I got a linear layout Im using layouts weights on. I want the first view to taker up 10% of the screen, the second view to take up 80% and the third view to be 10% of the screen. Something like this:

```
----------
view_1: 10% height
----------



view_2: 80% height




----------
view_3: 10% height
----------
```

Im trying to achive the result with this layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/gold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:background="@color/orange" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:background="@color/blue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

But I get this result:

[image]

Only when I set the weights to 33.3333 on all views it seems to work as expected. Ie all views have equal height. Any ide how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace:

```
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

with:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

in all three locations.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/gold" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:background="@color/orange" />

<View
    android:id="@+id/view3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@color/blue" />
```

the second view takes half of the space the rest shares the remaining space equally